# Multiple residence permit in EU

Tags: germany, eu, belgium

**Context**

I am working on a blue card from last 2 years. Me and my wife has independent residence permit (She has permanent EU residence)

**Question**

I got a research position in Belgium so I will move there however I want to maintain my German residence permit by shifting it from blue card to family reunion permit.

Can I do that? Our marriage is registered in Germany.

Comment: A German residence permit is for someone who resides in Germany.  What's the point of maintaining one if you no longer reside there?

Answer (score 1):

Blue card allows you to resettle to another EU country. With this way, you'll exchange your German Blue Card into your new Blue Card from another country. This is probably the most straightforward way to follow.

If you want to keep residence in Germany, you might try getting a permanent residence permit here (if you know German well enough, you should have applied for it after 21 months with Blue Card), apply for Belgium visa from scratch and ask German Ausländerbehörde to keep your residence permit claiming that your stay in Belgium will be just temporary (1-2 years). However, this is a tricky way and you better consult a lawyer about it.